# How to get a min/max int value from string?

Tags: javascript

I have a many elements in page whis `id = "item(\d{1,})"`. How to quickly get element id with a min value and max value of `(\d{1,})` regexp ?

Comment: Do you mean the IDs are of the form `item123`, `item42`, `item69682374534`?

Comment: what does this have to do with jQuery? :P

Comment: @jbabey, it could simply already be available and as such be a useful tool for accomplishing the task. Personally I think I'd start with getting all the number values since a regex isn't going to be able to compare them. Manually traverse to find lowest value, then `getElementById("item" + minValue);`. Not quick though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `querySelectorAll` if the browser supports it; all browsers *should* select it. IE has supported it since 8.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=item]");
var max = null;
var min = null;
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

   var number = elements[i].id.replace(/item/, "");

   if(max == null) {
      max = number;
      min = number;
   }

   else {
      max = (number > max) ? number : max;
      min = (number < min) ? number : min;
   }
}
```

If the browser doesn't support it, you would have to do something like this:

```
//assuming that you're looking for div; just replace it with the actual element 
//you're looking for
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("<div">); 

var max = null;
var min = null;
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if(/item\d+/.test(elements[i].id)) {
       var number = elements[i].id.replace(/item/, "");

       if(max == null) {
          max = number;
          min = number;
       }

       else {
          max = (number > max) ? number : max;
          min = (number < min) ? number : min;
       }
    }
}
```

Or if you're using jQuery:

```
var max = null;
var min = null;
jQuery("[id^=item]").each(function() {
    var number = this.id.replace(/item/, "");

    if(max == null) {
       max = number;
       min = number;
    }

    else {
       max = (number > max) ? number : max;
       min = (number < min) ? number : min;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get list of your IDs:

```
$j("[id^=item]").map(function(){ return Number(this.id.substr(4)); });
```

I don't think jQuery has any tools to quickly get min/max value, but it is pretty trivial to write yourself.

As per Vivin's request providing the trivial part:

```
var arr = $j("[id^=item]").map(function(){ return Number(this.id.substr(4)); }).sort();
var min = arr[0];
var max = arr[arr.length-1];
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @VivinPaliath The question was about using jQuery to get min/max values out of the element IDs. jQuery doesn't really cover math/array functions, so the answer is given to the extent covered by jQuery. If OP is really need to know now to get min/max values out of an array (which it doesn't seem like to me), then he has other more serious issues. Nice job on stealing the answer though.

Comment: The question isn't tagged with jQuery though. Also, using jQuery you can still get the max and min values by iterating over the id's that are returned.

Comment: @VivinPaliath It was when I wrote it.